# Latency problem on FF and safari and IE

Tags: php

so i've build a function to scan a dir based on a $_GET var, the code:

```
    $dir="img/".$_GET["gal"];
    $a=scandir($dir);
    $b=array_slice($a,2);


    for($i=1,$j=1;$i,$j<=count($b);$i++,$j++){
    $marginRight=($i==6||$i==12||$i==18||$i==24||$i==30||$i==36)?"margin-right: 0":"margin-right: 13px";
    if($i<10 && $j<10)
    echo '<div class="GalThumbs" style="'.$marginRight.'"><a href="'.$dir.'/'.$_GET["gal"].'-0'.$j.'.jpg"  rel="example3"><img src="'.$dir.'/'.$_GET["gal"].'-0'.$i.'.jpg"/></a></div>';
    else{
     echo '<div class="GalThumbs" style="'.$marginRight.'"><a href="'.$dir.'/'.$_GET["gal"].'-'.$j.'.jpg"  rel="example3"><img src="'.$dir.'/'.$_GET["gal"].'-'.$i.'.jpg"/></a></div>';
     }
   /* if($i==11)
    break;  */

}
```

if there are more than ten images to scan a latency occurs(redraw of the browser slowish)
i discover this using the commented:

```
if($i==11)
    break;
```

if it's :

```
  if($i==10)
        break;
```

there will be no latency. don't understand what's going on here..

Comment: Really low possibility that this is true. Got a URL for testing?

Comment: @tada: I tried a bit to work with your code, see the answer below. One thing #i can imagine: Check the images paths. Maybe images numbered 10 and above have the wrong url making rendering a bit of stuck with 404 responses, maybe redirects etc. How are files numbered on disk?

Comment: files are number like this  127thAtStNick-1.jpg, 127thAtStNick-2.jpg i've also try like this 127thAtStNick-01.jpg, 127thAtStNick-02.jpg  but still get latency

Comment: why should i sanitize the GET input? i am not making a DB request, how could this be 'attacked' by a malicious user?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your code, I think you are somehow lost in all that code and what it does. With a little bit of clean-up you should be able to debug your latency issue far easier.

Let's start with the for-loop:

```
for($i=1,$j=1;$i,$j<=count($b);$i++,$j++)
```

Both iterator variables are set in parallel. I'm sure you have thought about something when you wrote it, but this makes no sense. Try to reduce problems if you're unsure how to go on.

One variable does the job. Same here:

```
if($i<10 && $j<10)
```

And then I stumbled over this:

```
$marginRight=($i==6||$i==12||$i==18||$i==24||$i==30||$i==36)?"margin-right: 0":"margin-right: 13px";
```

You are actually looking for [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): Get the remainder of `$i` divided by `6`.

The if/else blocks both contain the same code. There is no need to use it at all.

Then I assume for debugging you want to quit the for-loop with break.

Next to that your code can benefit from indentation.

And the directory is actually only read to get the number of files, so the code can be reduced to get the count of files.

Let's try:

```
$gal = $_GET["gal"]; // FIXME sanitize the input
$dir = sprintf('img/%s', $gal);
$max = count(scandir($dir))-2;

for($i=1; $i<=$max; $i++)
{
    $marginRight = ($i % 6 ? '13px' : '0');
    $style = sprintf('margin-right: %s', $marginRight);        
    $src = sprintf('%s/%s-0%d.jpg', $dir, $gal, $i);      

    echo '<div class="GalThumbs" style="', htmlspecialchars($style), '">',
           '<a href="', htmlspecialchars($src), '" rel="example3">',
             '<img src="', htmlspecialchars($src),'"/>',
           '</a>',
         '</div>'
    ;

    // FIXME debug
    /* if($i==11) break;  */
}
```

Comment: just upgraded to safari 4.0 same thing , latency to almost crash the browser.

Comment: For example by using a proxy that shows you statistics. Some browsers have developer tools available that can show you more about the network connections as well. But this is maybe just too complicated. You probably don't have a real latency problem here, just too many images displayed in the browser or such.

Comment: yes but eleven images can be that much, and it's weird just because it goes beyond 10 the latency begins.(i've also tried same thing with a DB, same problem)

Comment: Check if the URLs of all images are correct. Next to that 10 images can create latency. Any additional connection can create latency as browsers are limiting the requests they send to the server.

Comment: Strange, if i disable images , php will render the same markup and latency dissapears

Comment: That are the network connections for the images then. Check if all URLs are correct. If not, that's something at least you can change. Everything else is up to the browser and the network.